# I am making a working backup of a ruby site and have no idea how to deploy it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rubber

The main "It works" index.html file shows. 
I don't know what else I need to do.
I copied the entire code-base and db and put up a new subdomain.

It's MySQL and ruby-on-rails with rubber([wr0ngway](https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber/wiki/Quick-Start)) and [capistrano](http://kris.me.uk/2011/10/28/rails-rvm-passenger-capistrano-git-apache.html).

What I have done:

- Set up a new subdomain with the "Passenger" options in my Dreamhost account.
- Create a new MySQL server and migrate over all the data.
- Upload all files.

That's it. It should work right?!?

I know there must be some ruby config files somewhere that needs to be customized so that ruby can

- appreciate its new home
- point to the correct db

I know I need to know ruby better and RTM & STFW.
Ruby is not my background and my "ramp-up time" is probably irritating my new employer. 
Is there a quick-&-dirty way to get this working in the meanwhile before I log my 45th hour of discovery learning. Should the gems work without being uninstalled and reinstalled?

Any/All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Hartl's [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). Chapter 1. From Zero to Deploy. Although he is talking about deploying to Heroku this got me up and running on a different host the first time.

Comment: This tutorial takes "Three long days" to get through.

Comment: I will do this but I was hoping to find out which config files need to be slightly modified to get this working. The only difference between the old rails site and the new environment is a new url and a new database.

Comment: what does your routes.rb file look like with regards to "root :to" ?